# Where are the midrashim about the Jews intermarrying during the Babylonian Exile?

Tags: midrash, intermarriage, ezra-nechemya, babylonian-exile

Someone told me that there is an argument between different midrashim about how many Jews intermarried during the Babylonian Exile. I don't know where to look to find these midrashim. Does anyone know where they are?

(I have been told that a good place to look is in the [yalkut me'am loaz](https://www.eichlers.com/books/bible-and-tanach/torah-anthology-me-am-loez.html), but I don't have that sefer)

Comment: This article addresses the issue:  https://www.thetorah.com/article/jews-intermarried-not-only-in-judea-but-also-in-babylonia

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi It's true that that article is RELATED to my question, but it doesn't actually solve my question at all, because it doesn't quote any of the midrashim, nor does it offer a NUMBER for the Jews that intermarried during that ERA.